# Pantheios rolling file appender?

Tags: c

I have used log4C and it is great. However, I would like to get Pantheios working as well and was wondering if it supports a rolling file appender? I mean if I have something logging to file in Production I need it to be a rolling file?

Also, stupid question but let's say I have DEBUG, INFO and ERROR type logs when using Pantheios, how do you limit to only seeing INFO (for example) using some "sort of config file" like with log4C?

Thanks for the help, any advise would be greatly appreciated ;-)

Lynton

Answer (score 0):

I started evaluating Pantheios since yesterday. Therefore my reply may not be perfect.

1) For rolling file, you can customize the back-end to roll the file by yourself (pantheios_be_file_setFilePath), or use log4c  as your logging transport in the back-end. :-)

2) Customize the front-end and make pantheios_fe_isSeverityLogged() function return true only for INFO. You can make it configurable by picking up the settings from .ini file.